# Control migration of a spring jersey app to webflux through a feature flag

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-jersey

We are thinking of how to migrate spring jersey app to webflux gradually, by converting jersey services to webflux controllers, and converting jersey filters to webfilters one by one, controlled by a feature flag. Since webflux can run on modern servlet containers, I am thinking of mapping the original path to a servlet that just does the forwarding based on the value of the feature flag. However, as I understand, spring boot does not allow webflux to co-exist with spring MVC/Jersey. What's a best way to migrate existing app to webflux?

Comment: webflux does not run with servlets. It's run using the non-servlet based server netty. Best way is simply to have two applications, and switch over.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf that is not true. webflux can run over servlet container (albeit modern ones with support for 3.1+ servlet standard that supports async servlets)

Comment: in theory yes, but i have heard there has been issues on the github, when people have tried it, so stability wise im not so sure of it yet.